# My Expo camera doesn't work because of a bug with Image Picker and permissions

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, expo, frontend

I'm developing with React Native and Expo. I believe the error is with the Image Picker and your permissions, because when i start the application in production, without permissions preload, i click in the component of the camera function, it request my permissions and work good. However, when i close and open again, now with the permissions, doesn't work. And i know the problem is with the permissions, because if i remove in the permissions in the phone's settings, it does work good again.

```
Error: Call to function 'ExponentImagePicker.launchCameraAsync' has been rejected.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to launch an unregistered ActivityResultLauncher with contract expo.modules.imagepicker.contracts.CameraContract@ebffc59 and input CameraContractOptions(uri=content://com.test.testapp.ImagePickerFileProvider/cached_expo_files/ImagePicker/0f946a22-9efc-4706-8b23-d2d3fc8711f0.jpeg, options=expo.modules.imagepicker.ImagePickerOptions@c77c01e). You must ensure the ActivityResultLauncher is registered before calling launch()] code: 'ERR_UNEXPECTED' }
```

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image, Alert } from "react-native";
import { styles } from "./styles";
import { Entypo, Feather, FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
import * as MediaLibrary from "expo-media-library";
import { defaultStyles, globalStyles } from "../../../../globalStyles";

const ImageInspect = React.memo(function ImageType({
  data,
  setData,
  title,
}) {
  const [photo, setPhoto] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!!data?.title?.files) {
      setPhoto(data?.title?.files[0]);
    }
  }, [data]);

  const getImageOfCamera = async () => {
    try {
      let permissionResult = await ImagePicker.getCameraPermissionsAsync();
      if (permissionResult.status !== "granted") {
        permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
      }
      if (permissionResult.status !== "granted") {
        alert("You must turn on camera permissions to record a video.");
      } else {
        const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
          mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
          aspect: [4, 3],
          allowsEditing: false,
          quality: 0.7,
        });

        await MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(result.assets[0].uri);

        if (!result.canceled) {
          setPhoto(result.assets[0].uri);
          setData({
            ...data,
            [data?.value]: {
              title: data?.title,
              //   value: item?.value,
              files: [result.assets[0].uri],
            },
          });
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      Alert.alert("ERRO AO ABRIR A CAMERA", JSON.stringify(err));
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
      <Text>{title}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={getImageOfCamera}
      >
        {!!photo ? (
          <View
            style={[globalStyles.marginTopMini, globalStyles.alignItemsCenter]}
          >
            <Image
              source={{ uri: photo }}
              style={{ width: 120, height: 100, borderRadius: 6 }}
            />
          </View>
        ) : (
          <View>
            <>
              <Feather name="camera" size={24} />
              <Text> Abrir câmera</Text>
            </>
          </View>
        )}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
});

export default ImageInspect;
```

I was trying to delete the permissions every time the app closed, but I couldn't.